# Migrating questions to Christianity.SE if the site closes down?

Tags: discussion

[This announcement](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/why-biblical-hermeneutics-isnt-closing) is a timely relief. However, in the event that the core members of Hermeneutics.SE began to get weary and the site stats continued to slide, would there be a chance to migrate all the quality questions to Christianity.SE or Judaism.SE, as appropriate, before closing down? There is so much good material on this site, it would be a pity to loose so many neat questions and answers. (Of course, it would be pity to even have to shut down.)

Comment: Some questions are duplicated on both sites. Any idea what we will do with them?

Comment: @Monica I've taken note of your comment and do my best to see your request is honoured. I take Shog9's announcement as a demonstration of his faith in this site, not primarily a warning that we will shut down.

Comment: @GoneQuiet: That can be taken care of. I'm pretty sure that if they get migrated and you don't have a linked account there, they would just show up as userN anyway. If not and a user gets created or something weird like that, as a moderator there I can see that it gets nuked. If worst comes to worse, just ping me in BH chat and we'll get it taken care of.

Comment: Meanwhile, _everybody back to work_! <whip sound effect>

Comment: @Caleb the user will not auto-create but the 'ghost' user would still carry the name if I remember correctly

Comment: @JackDouglas: I kind of thought that might be the case. Worst case I think we have the user create an account, associate it, then we nuke it all in one swift motion, then it would anonymity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Even the poorly announced batch of shutdowns this week has been given a couple weeks go do things like go through and migrate anything that would be useful to a site with a crossover scope. In this case I think a large amount of content would make it's way to C.SE.

Also be aware that they provide full data dumps from shutdown sites. Obviously it's a harder to use format, but the data isn't lost to the world in the event of a site shutdown.

I think the thing to do is focus on keeping up a steady flow of quality content and promoting to interested experts so that we never have to face those issues!

Comment: +1 I am a contingency thinker, thus the question. But I strongly agree that *the thing to do is focus on keeping up a steady flow of quality content and promoting to interested experts so that we never have to face those issues!*